# Adding alphabetically items to QComboBox using PySide

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I would like to add new items to my *QtGui.QComboBox*. Where the new items should appers alphabetically in my *QtGui.QComboBox*.

Is there a way to define a police, that the list is always alphabetical sorted after using *QtGui.QComboBox.addItem(value)*?

In not, how could i sort my *QtGui.QComboBox* items?

**Additional Info**:
Python v3.4.1 and PySide v1.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `QComboBox.InsertPolicy` property to `QComboBox.InsertAlphabetically`.

[Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#InsertPolicy-enum), [PySide docs](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QComboBox.html?highlight=qcombobox#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.InsertPolicy)

---

The above (apparently) applies only for user entering data. In code, insert all items and sort underlying *model*.

```
combobox.model().sort(0)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tired _foo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)_ and then _foo.setInsertPolicy(QtGui.QComboBox.InsertAlphabetically)_ or _foo.InsertPolicy(QtGui.QComboBox.InsertAlphabetically)_ without the wished result. What am I missing?